# How to send Radio Button value to server in android?

Tags: android

I have two `RadioButton` named as married,unmarried what I have to do that is when user check married radio button I have to send value of `radioButton` "married" to server using `jsons` and same as in unmarried .How can I do that.

Here is a field of json code:-

```
jsonObject.put("maritalstatus", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code:

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
 String selectedText = ((RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString(); 

 jsonObject.put("maritalstatus", selectedText);
```

To set radio button checked:

```
String status =  jsonObject.getString("maritalstatus");
if(status.equals("married")){
   radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(0).getId());
}else{
   radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(1).getId());
}
```

Comment: thats work but in response i get martial status after that I have check that response may be married or unmarried

Comment: Sorry i am not getting ur comment. What response u r getting and what response u need?

Comment: I am gettig married from server when I get maaried then I have to set married radioButoon check and if got unmarried then I have to set Unmarried RdaioButton checked

Answer (score 0):

First, for each RadioButton element you need to set a tag for retrieving later:

```
    marriedRadioButton.setTag("married");
unmarriedRadioButton.setTag("unmarried")


RadioGroup rdGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    String text = radioButton.getTag();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("maritalstatus", text);
    // Now you need to send the json to the server through an AsyncTask
    SendJsonTask sendJsonTask = new SendJsonTask();
    sendJsonTask.execute(jsonObject.toString());
}});

private class SendJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url = new URL("http://domaintoreceive.com/pagetoreceive");

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toURI());

    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params[0], "UTF-8"));

    // Set up the header types needed to properly transfer JSON
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");

    // Execute POST
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}}
```

Don't forget to catch all the required exceptions.

Regards.